# Bootstrap span collapsing when child is given absolute position

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I'm using a bootstrap row, and giving it more span children that it should have, because I found that helps get a nice grid working, while preserving responsiveness.

Each element has a child, and an element that is shown using jQuery, like this:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="span2">
    <div class="inner-element">
         Content here
         <div class="hidden-element">
               More content here
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
...

</div>
```

When a certain button inside `.span2` is clicked, the `.hidden-element` div grows with `slideDown();` and the inner-element gets a `position:absolute` CSS, so that it goes over the spans that are below and doesn't alter the grid.

This setup works perfectly fine when it's done in a .span2 element that's not in the rightmost corner of the page (on the `.row`'s corner)

You can see this problem in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcX7v/) example. You can see that clicking on "Example #1" works fine, not collapsing the parent element, while clicking on "Example #2" makes the `.span2` element collapse, making the next `.span2` element to jump up one row.

What is the cause of this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem resides in the `.span2` element's `height` attribute collapsing. Setting the height synthetically through JavaScript prior to the animation does the trick, as shown in [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kcX7v/1/). Hence the correct way to do the animation is:

```
var box = item.closest('.span2');
```

On open:

```
box.css("height", box.height()+"px");
```

On close:

```
box.css("height", "auto");
```

This forces the parent element to have a fixed height and not collapse.